# Search for list values in a csv file python

Tags: python, csv

There is a csv file, there is a unique id column and a column with a date. The task of this section of the code is that you need to scan the lines using the id key, find the id in the line, write the line to a new file called id. Faced with the problem that the interpreter returns an error by id. Although everything is logical and correct. Where did I go wrong?

id, Numder, Date
123456, 89654535556, 25.11.2021 15:35:00
321654, 96554412255, 23.11.2021 18:50:00
524163, 38095224444, 18.11.2021 13:30:00

```
from csv import DictReader
from csv import DictWriter
from os.path import isfile

def export_csv(user_id, master_csv, fieldnames, key_id, extension=".csv"):
filename = user_id + extension
file_exists = isfile(filename)

with open(file=master_csv) as in_file, open(
    file=filename, mode="a", newline=""
) as out_file:

    # Create reading and writing objects
    csv_reader = DictReader(in_file)
    csv_writer = DictWriter(out_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    # Only write header once
    if not file_exists:
        csv_writer.writeheader()

    # Go through lines and match ids
    for line in csv_reader:
        if line[key_id] == user_id:

             # Modify line and append to file
            line = {k: v.strip() for k, v in line.items() if k in fieldnames}
            csv_writer.writerow(line)
export_csv(
   user_id="512863",
   master_csv="master.csv",
   fieldnames=["Number", "Date"],
   key_id="id")
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/sedei/PycharmProjects/convector/1.py", line 58, in 
export_csv(
File "C:/Users/sedei/PycharmProjects/convector/1.py", line 52, in export_csv
if line[key_id] == user_id:
KeyError: 'id'

Comment: Your sample data shows the column heading "id" whereas in your code you're expecting "ID". Dictionary keys are case-sensitive

Comment: Changed the register, everything exactly returns an error

Comment: insert `print(line)` before `if line[key_id] == user_id:` and the last line it prints for you before raising an exception will be the issue